# How CDN detection works in webpgatest

Tags: performance, cdn, webpagetest

I did some performance optimization (and I test it with webpagetest.org) but I still have problem with CDN detection. It looks like on screen:
[image]

All requests (except first which is http request for html) with red X icon in last column are:

- for assets (css, js, images or fonts)
- from same domain (different than main application domain)

What should I do to have assets detected as CDN on this test???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPageTest just [uses a list of the most common CDN providers](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/agent/wpthook/cdn.h) and then parse the assets request header :

```
CDN_PROVIDER_HEADER cdnHeaderList[] = {
    {"server", "cloudflare", _T("Cloudflare")},
```

to check (in this case) if there is a `server` key containing *cloudflare*.

Comment: It check also if the CNAME of a domain match the DNS of a known CDN

Answer (score 0):

Are the assets actually hosted on a CDN?

If it's one of the common CDNs that WebPageTest will automatically detect it.

If it's one of the less common ones you may have to update the code and issue a pull request - there are plenty of examples of what needs changing in the closed PRs.